# Getting Roslyn SemanticModel from ProjectItem in Visual Studio extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, vsx

I'm writing a Visual Studio 2015 extension which looks at the contents of the class the user has right clicked on.

I've got the `ProjectItem`, but how do you get the `SemanticModel` (and `SyntaxTree`) from this?

I need to look up some types of properties declared in the file. I've written a code analyzer which gives you the `SemanticModel` on the context but I can't figure out how to get it here. Searches haven't turned up anything useful. I've found how to parse the `SyntaxTree` by reading the file contents, but it won't be so easy with the `SemanticModel`. Ideally I'd hook in to the model VS has already built for the file.

Comment: Yeah, there should be some way for you to get to the VisualStudioWorkspace. We have easy helpers to go from the workspace to the FileCodeModel, but curiously I don't know if we have one the other way. Just to check, what did you originally start with that gave you the ProjectItem?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski I have a Command running from a context menu item on SolutionExplorer. When it's invoked I'm using DTE2.ToolWindows.SolutionExplorer.SelectedItems, then casting the Object property to ProjectItem.

Answer (score 6):

Figured it out.

1. Upgrade your project to target .NET framework 4.6.2.
2. Install the [Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices/).
3. Downgrade System.Collections.Immutable from 1.2.0 to 1.1.37, otherwise you get a MissingMethodException in the code later.
4. In the package class's `Initialize` method, grab the VisualStudioWorkspace. I save it in a static property here to grab later:

   ```
   var componentModel = (IComponentModel)this.GetService(typeof(SComponentModel));
   VisualStudioWorkspace = componentModel.GetService<VisualStudioWorkspace>();
   ```

Now you can get the Document with SyntaxTree and SemanticModel from the file path:

```
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution solution = CreateUnitTestBoilerplateCommandPackage.VisualStudioWorkspace.CurrentSolution;
DocumentId documentId = solution.GetDocumentIdsWithFilePath(inputFilePath).FirstOrDefault();
var document = solution.GetDocument(documentId);

SyntaxNode root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync();
SemanticModel semanticModel = await document.GetSemanticModelAsync();
```